# Logical OR for Bit-string in Python

Tags: python, binary

What i want to do is have the result of logical OR for two bit-strings. For example:

```
    a='010010'
    b='000101'
    c=LOGIC_OR(a,b)
    c
    010111
```

The error i encounter most of the time is when I convert 'b' from string to binary it removes leading zeros. Others methods i have used convert 'a' and 'b' to integers. Generally nothing is working and help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of alternative methods.

Third-party [bitarray](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray) library:

```
from bitarray import bitarray

a='010010'
b='000101'

logical_or_bitarray = bitarray(a) | bitarray(b)  # output: bitarray('010111')
logical_or_string = ''.join(map(str, map(int, logical_or_bitarray)))  # output: '010111'
```

Python strings:-

```
a='010010'
b='000101'

def compare_bits(A, B):
    c_1 = str(int(A) | int(B))
    c = (len(A) - len(c_1))*'0' + str(c_1)
    return c

compare_bits(a, b)
```

Comment: Does this function also work if there are no,or many leading zeros? I ask because i don't understand the " *'0' " when you define c. Thanks anyways

Comment: `str(int(A) | int(B))` removes leading 0's. We need to add back a certain number of 0's, precisely `len(A) - len(c_1)`. The `*0` repeats a string by the preceding integer.

Comment: For the string method, I recommend COLDSPEED's answer which utilises str.zfill.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert them to integers with `int` specifying the base to be `2`. Then, perform a *bitwise OR* operation and convert the result to a bit string with `bin`.

```
>>> c = int(a, 2) | int(b, 2))
>>> c
23
```

If you want to print the result as a bit string, use `str.format`. If you're on python-3.6, you can also use f-strings.

```
>>> '{:b}'.format(c)
'10111'
```

```
>>> print(f"{c:b}")
10111
```

To capture leading zeros with respect to `a`/`b`, use `str.zfill` -

```
>>> f"{c:b}".zfill(len(a))
'010111'
```

Comment: Probably the next question OP will ask is regarding the presence of `b`, slice it to show them what they desire. also the string formatting to show extra 0 at start ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should convert to `int` objects and do numerical operations in the numerical data type. Then you use string-formatting when you need to see it. If you have Python 3.6, using f-strings makes this trivial:

```
>>> a='010010'
>>> b='000101'
>>> a = int(a, base=2) # we should be ints
>>> b = int(b, base=2) # we should be ints
>>> c = a | b # operations natural and built in
>>> print(f"{c:b}") # use formatting when you need it
10111
```

Read the [string formatting spec's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax). You can make them do whatever you desire. Using a fill value of `'0'` and a width of `'6'`:

```
>>> print(f"{c:0>6b}")
010111
```

And this is cool too:

```
>>> pad='0'
>>> width = 6
>>> print(f"{c:{pad}>{width}b}")
010111
```